# Getting last 30 days of records

Tags: mysql, sql, datediff

I have a table called 'Articles' in that table I have 2 columns that will be essential in creating the query I want to create. The first column is the `dateStamp` column which is a datetime type column. The second column is the `Counter` column which is an int(255) column. The `Counter` column technically holds the views for that particular field.

I am trying to create a query that will generate the last 30 days of records. It will then order the records based on most viewed. This query will only pick up 10 records. The current query I have is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Articles
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, dateStamp, getdate()) BETWEEN 0 and 30
LIMIT 10
) TOP10
ORDER BY Counter DESC
```

This query is not displaying any records, but I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using SQL Server syntax if you tag your question MySQL?  The query in your question will not run in any database that I can think of.

Comment: `day` is a reserved word in MYSQL; you should rename it to avoid weird issues.  You may also want to check the format of the dates before comparing them.

Comment: @Sablefoste Look again. It's a keyword, but not a reserved word. There's no (R) next it in the list of keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL version of the query would look like this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Articles a
WHERE a.dateStamp >= CURDATE() - interval 30 day 
ORDER BY a.counter DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Your query is generating an error.  You should look at that error before fixing the query.

The query would look different in SQL Server.

Comment: I'll accept your answer soon, but it's working successfully. Thanks a lot! Could you tell me what the a is in that query?

Comment: @user2896120 . . . It is a table alias.  You should use them and qualified column names.

Comment: For readability and semantics, use the `AS` word in line 2, so that it reads `FROM Articles AS a`.  Not necessary for the query, though.  ;)

Comment: @Sablefoste . . . I disagree 100%.  The use of `as` in the `FROM` clause adds nothing to the query.  On the other hand, the use of `as` for column aliases is quite important.  So, always use them for column aliases; never for table aliases.

Comment: @GordonLinoff respectfully, I too disagree.  The fact that he asked what the `a` was for meant the `AS` word had some utility, in helping explain the purpose.  In very long and complex queries, spacing, formatting and using the alias helps less experienced developers figure out what is going on much quicker.  This makes maintaining code easier.